# Axios params doesnt work but hardcoded url works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Axios shows `Error: OAUTH verification failed.` when i use, "params"  in the axios object but when i hard code the post request it works fine !

This is my axios object:

```
const blockKey  = req.body; // { "blockKey" : "1sf2f" }
  
  const request_data = {
    url: `http://travel/bookticket`, //temp url for Stackoverflow purpose
    method: 'post',
  };
  
  axios({
      method: request_data.method,
      url: request_data.url,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          ...oauth.oauth.toHeader(oauth.oauth.authorize(request_data)),
      },
      params: {
         blockKey
     }
  })
    .then((response) => {
        res.send(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.send(error.response.data)
    });
```

The above shows error, but

```
   const blockKey  = req.body.blockKey; { "1sf2f" }
  
  const request_data = {
    url: `http://travel/bookticket?blockKey=${blockKey}`,
    method: 'post',
  };
  
  axios({
      method: request_data.method,
      url: request_data.url,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          ...oauth.oauth.toHeader(oauth.oauth.authorize(request_data)),
      }
  })
    .then((response) => {
        res.send(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        res.send(error.response.data)
    });
```

Am using this npm pack for [oAuth 1.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth-1.0a) auth. Please help, i know hardcoded works but i want to know whats the mistake on params one !

Note: I have even tried using "qs" but no use

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that from the error case, blockKey is an object not a string. It needs to be a string for how it is used in the params object.
change it to a string

```
const { blockKey } = req.body;
```

Or

```
const blockKey = req.body.blockKey
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: As i mentioned, i have used qs package to stringfy it ! its not the issue !

Comment: ```qs.stringify(req.body)```  which will give ```blockKey=1sf2f```

Comment: if you log blockKey after that assignment it will give you 'blockKey=12f2f' but what you want is blockKey to be '12f2f'. qs is not for that scenerio

Comment: I belive you havent got my question

Comment: @samanthas you want to pass `{ blockKey: "sameValue"}` to axios params but what you are doing is passing `{ blockKey: {blockKey: "sameValue"}}` so the answer of @urchmaney is right

Comment: No, as am passing in params so it automatically adds to url as pramas ! So i dont need to split ! As you seen on first example which i have hardcoded at URL end, i have splitted

Comment: @samanthas do `console.log(error.response.request.responseURL)` and you will understand

Answer (score 0):

The below code is extracted from the official axios documentation and has been tested.
[Axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios)

```
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

Comment: I have checked this , and in my case it isnt working !

Answer (score 0):

In first case you are not using a key:value pair, instead an object inside a block. You can instead use a spread operator for "blockKey" or not use block for the "params" key and directly use "blockKey".

Comment: Am not getting what your saying ? can you post a example ?

Comment: @Shivani patel- what you've posted could have made for a good comment- for a good answer, could you demonstrate your answer with a code example please?

Comment: What I have written in words is accurately demonstrated by @evgeni-fotia in the comments of this post. Hope that helps. If not then then I'll be happy post code examples.